# How to store and load multi-column index pandas dataframes with parquet

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, parquet, fastparquet

I have a dataset similar to:

```
initial_df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 10.898}, {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 1.88}, {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 108.1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 10.898}])
initial_df.set_index(['a', 'b'], inplace=True)
```

I am able to store it completely fine (append = False plays no role in this example but is used with a variable in the actual code):

```
initial_df.to_parquet('test.parquet', engine='fastparquet', compression='GZIP', append=False, index=True)
```

I am also able to load it completely fine:

```
read_df = pd.read_parquet('test.parquet', engine='fastparquet')
read_df
```

This is how the dataset looks:

[data in dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrLLk.png)

[dataframe.info() output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7FTM.png)

But this is where the **issue begins**. In my application I will have to append a new dataframe to existing files and index (in this example 'a') will be incremented while index (in this example 'b') will be looped.

```
additional_df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 2, 'b': 0, 'c': 10.898}, {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 1.88}, {'a': 3, 'b': 0, 'c': 108.1}, {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 10.898}])
additional_df.set_index(['a', 'b'], inplace=True)
```

After I store this additional data using:

```
additional_df.to_parquet('test.parquet', engine='fastparquet', compression='GZIP', append=True, index=True)
```

When I try to retrieve it with:

```
read_df = pd.read_parquet('test.parquet', engine='fastparquet')
```

I get an **error**: RuntimeError: Different dictionaries encountered while building categorical
**Error location** pandas\io\parquet.py:358

VERSIONS:
python: 3.10.8
pandas: 1.5.1
fastparquet: 0.8.3 (also tested with older 0.5.0)

I tried debugging the source code to better understand why the RuntimeError is raised, but the only thing I was able to figure out from that was that the **read_col** function from **fastparquet\core.py:170** is called multiple times for each column causing the index to be written twice more than required and on the second attempt to write it the error is raised.

I also played around with **index** parameter of read_parquet but I do not believe that this is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have **not really solved** the specific problem I had and would still appreciate any input anyone has, but I was able to **work around** it using a method suggested by a friend.

Instead of appending to one file I am now using a directory of files where each one has the same DataFrame structure. The functions I had problems with were replaced as such:

- **Appending** --> Just write a new file to the output directory (each unqiue and/or seperate DataFrame structure should have its own directory).

`pd.to_parquet("./directory/new_file.parquet", engine='pyarrow', compression='gzip', index=True)`

- **Read all data together** --> works by just reading the directory (all DataFrames in
  directory will be merged, they **must have the same structure!**)

`pd.read_parquet("./directory", engine='pyarrow')`

Also I am now using *pyarrow* as an engine instead of *fastparquet*.